# is there way to use linear acceleration in expo react native?

Tags: react-native, expo

we are trying to build human activity recognition app using react native using expo?
is there a way to get linear accleration from the device or we have to calculate using accelerometer sensor?

Comment: Expo provides an Accelerometer in their expo-sensors SDK https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/accelerometer/

Comment: what is the difference between the DeviceMotion acceleration and Accelerometer in expo?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.